# Why is the content of my iframe not showing in chrome but displaying on Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, iframe, server, reader

Im trying to display the content of an iframe in Google Chrome, but shows me an error. But when I open it in Internet Explorer it displays properly. By the way the file is a pdf. I checked the the Google console, it shows: `Unexpected server response 0 Cant retriview the PDF file`

[image: Cant display PDF file in iframe]